# Passing parameters with react router v4 and using them in url's

Tags: reactjs, react-router, parameter-passing, axios

I'm having problems with passing my parameters, but my way of thinking is probably wrong so:

My App.js with routes

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <Router>
      <div className="container">
      (...)
      <Route path="/product/:id" component={ProductPage} ></Route>
      (...)
      </div>
    </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

and my review section with array of comments

```
    class ReviewSection extends Component {

      constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {rates:[]};
    }


    componentDidMount() {

        axios.get('http://oceneo-api.herokuapp.com/api/products/1/rates')
           .then(res => {
             console.log(res)
             const rates = res.data;
             this.setState({rates})
           })
           .catch(error => console.log(error))
         }
 render(){
        return(

            <div className="container products">
                {this.state.rates.map(rate => 

                <div className="row" key={rate.id}>
              (...)
```

The main problem for me is to change the api link with something like `localhost:3001/product/2` which would give desired `/api/products/2/rates` instead of `/api/products/1/rates`.

Comment: What do you mean? You mean you want to be able to change your api url? (btw: Your `Route` component is wrong. A `Route` component has no ending tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Route component is passing parameters to the rendered component so when you check props of `ProductPage` component you will see `match` prop and it contains key named `params`. Here is an example https://codesandbox.io/s/1y773j6kk4

Comment: using this example I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined which happend before, but I never managed to fix it

Comment: Could you prepare sandbox with your version where the error occurs? If you have nested components you should use `withRotuter` (https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md) or pass the data from parent component to the child component. I updated my sandbox maybe that will help.

Comment: I gave you a clue about the `withRouter` but you didn't use it. Here is fixed your example https://codesandbox.io/s/18oxl8nwy3

Comment: I used it, but forgot about including it in export, thats why it didnt work for me, now to use that parameter as an variable in api url? tried few things, but nothing seems to be working

Comment: Select `id` from the `props` (like it was in render in my example) and then use template string like here https://codesandbox.io/s/v36n3k9yx7. You cannot fetch the data in codesandbox because of CORS.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i tried using ${id} first plus bunch of other versions, but the problem was that I used ' ' instead of  ` ` each time, small things that matter :|